# Deleting the images with current date from the backup folder

Tags: vb.net

I have backup folder where there are images with current date and the past date, i need help in deleting the images form the backup folder which are in current date.

I just tried to delete the images from the backup folder using the below code:

```
For Each filepath As String In Directory.GetFiles(StrErrorInfo)
    File.Delete(filepath)
Next

For Each filepath As String In Directory.GetFiles(StrErrorInfo)
    File.Delete(filepath)
Next
```

The above code will only delete the files or images from the backup folder and not particularly with the current date file.

I need help in deleting the files with the current date from the bakcup folder.

Comment: Create a `DirectoryInfo`, call `GetFiles` to get `FileInfo` objects, filter list (loop or LINQ) by the appropriate property and call `Delete` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for deleting all files of this day

```
Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("directory")

For Each fi In di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim creationDate as Date = fi.CreationTime
    If creationDate = date.now()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fi)
    End if
Next
```